# Getting Eclipse to wrap the parenthetical of a for loop

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

I understand the importance of succinct, clear code and that code line wrapping should be avoided, if possible. However, the requirement for this project is that no line should go beyond column 80 and I'm being asked to use verbose variable naming. Therefore, something as simple as a for loop parenthetical will need to be wrapped and that's where I'm finding Eclipse falling short.

It doesn't appear that Eclipse is capable of wrapping the parenthetical of a for loop or preserving the wrapping set. For example, my initialization statement, expression and update/counter are on separate lines like so:

```
for (initialization;
  expression;
  update/counter;)
{
  //code...
}
```

When pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, Eclipse makes it:

```
for (initialization; expression; update/counter;)
{
  //code...
}
```

Is there a way to get Eclipse to preserve this formatting. I've created a custom Eclipse formatter, but can't find any setting that will wrap the for loop parenthetical. I did see one post that suggested using `//`, but that won't work inside of a for loop's parenthesis.

Comment: I think your company needs to finally try them those wide screens. :-)

Comment: Would using `; //` instead of `;` do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not remember of an option to preserve the line feeds after each of the for's "initialization", "expression", "update". The rest can be done, but not the wrapping inside the for loop's parenthesis.

If you really need to preserve such a wrapping, you may want to disable the formatter altogether on these lines? If you go to the formater settings (Window > preferences > java > code style > formatter, then click "edit..."), then on the "Off/On Tags" tab (appeared in Eclipse 3.6 IIRC), you can enable tags to disable the formatter on specific parts of the code.

With the default tags, that would give something like :

```
// @formatter:off
for (initialization;
  expression;
  update/counter)
// @formatter:on
{
  //code...
}
```

Comment: Ouch. My eyes hurt... And my fingers would too if I were to try this. ;-)

Comment: @Kos never told that this was an eye-friendly solution :p. Though these off/on tags sure come in handy when trying to respect a client's strangest requirements as far as code formatting goes.

Comment: Thank you. While I know this isn't perfect, it's good enough and allows me to use ctrl + shift + f freely without having to worry about the for's initialization. Normally, I wouldn't worry about this, but with the requirement to use verbose variable naming coupled with column 80 limitations, this solution will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this way:

```
for (/**/initialization;
/**/expression;
/**/update/counter;)
/**/{
  //code...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Velthune. It's good to see alternatives to meeting this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
for (initialization; //
expression; //
update/counter) {
  // code...
}
```